# AngularJS: Assign variables to $scope after AJAX call

Tags: angularjs

I am sooo close I can smell the finish line --

When my app starts, I harvest the login information from the user (it's an AngularJS SPA so I can get it easy from spInfoContext) and I check to see if the user is a returning user by searching a list called **itiUsers** for the userId. If no records are found, I immediately create a new record in **itiUsers** and then present a form for the new user to enter the information that I can't grab from SharePoint. The record is created properly. When the promise returns, I am trying to populate the $scope.current_user object so that it would be the same as if this were a returning user -- that's so I only have to have one My Preferences form.

However when I log out $scope after the record is created, current_user is empty.

Here's my Controller function (i reduced values for brevity and I tried to bold the problem line):

```
$.when(SharePointJSOMService.getCurrentUser())
    .done(function(jsonObject){
        if(jsonObject.d.results.length < 1 || jsonObject.d.results.newUser ){
        // new user
        $.when(SharePointJSOMService.getLoggedInUser())
            .done(function(jsonObject){
            $scope.loggedInUser = jsonObject.d;
            $scope.isNewUser = true;
            $.when(SharePointJSOMService.createNewUser($scope))
                .done(function(jsonObject){
                **$scope.current_user.DisplayName = $scope.loggedInUser.Title;
                              console.log($scope);**
                })
                .fail(function(err){
                $scope.prefPane = true;
                console.info(JSON.stringify(err)); 
            });
            })
            .fail(function(err){
            $scope.prefPane = true;
            console.info(JSON.stringify(err)); 
            });
            $scope.prefPane = true; // force preference pane
            $scope.taskClose = true;
            $scope.$apply();
        } else {
            // existing user
            $scope.isNewUser = false;
            $scope.prefPane = false; // hide preference pane
            $scope.current_user = jsonObject.d.results[0];
            switch($scope.current_user.Role){
                case 'USR':
                $scope.projectClose = 'true';
                break;
                case 'PMG':
                $scope.projectClose = 'false';
                break;
            default:
                $scope.projectClose = 'true';
                break;
             } // end switch
             $scope.$apply();
            } // end if
        })
        .fail(function(err){
             $scope.prefPane = true;
             console.info(JSON.stringify(err)); 
        });
```

Comment: On the first block you set `$scope.loggedInUser` and on the second (existing user) block you set `$scope.currentUser`. Is that correct?

Comment: yes. loggedInUser contains the information SharePoint has about the user. current_user contains the information I am maintaining on a user in the itiUsers table. Every use will have loggedInUser information but only existing users will have current_user info. BUT I have to assign the information that is not edited in the Preferences Pane to current_user so that they Prefs form will work. That's where this is breaking down at the "$scope.current_user.DisplayName = $scope.loggedInUser.Title;" line. Should I push it instead of assign it?

Answer (score 0):

It crashes because you are trying to set `$scope.current_user.DisplayName` after creating a new user but $scope.current_user object is undefined. Try instead:

```
$scope.current_user = {
   DisplayName: $scope.loggedInUser.Title
}
```

Comment: Nope, current_user is still empty. However, I tried $window.location.reload and when the refresh happened, there is NOW a record in itiUsers so current_user is populated.

Comment: I also tried $scope.$apply(); right after your code and current_user remains empty until I refresh the page - not what I am looking for in a SPA.